# Vue2 router with multiple, unordered, optional params

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but here's what i'm trying to do:

I'm working on a page to show search results of different products. The products have many multiple filters (e.g size, weight, color, country etc).
I'd like the url to 'describe' those filters.

I'm able to do something pretty basic with '?' (e.g: /color/:color?/country/:country). But it forces a specific order, and all sections in the url need to be entered. I'm dealing with over 10 filters, and some of them can have multiple colors.

A non Vue option I am considering would be something like: example.com/search/?weight=10-20&color=blue&color=red&country=usa.

This would require using Window.history.push, and parsing the queryString with javascript, while I probably won't be able to use the VueRouter at all.

I'm not experienced with Vue.js so any ideas are recommended.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`$route.query`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) to access the query parameters from the current URL. No need to parse it yourself.

Your template could access the query params directly:

```
<div v-if="$route.query.weight">weight: {{ $route.query.weight }}</div>
<div v-if="$route.query.country">country: {{ $route.query.country }}</div>
<div v-if="$route.query.color">color: {{ $route.query.color }}</div>
```

And your script could access the params like this:

```
methods: {
  logQueryParams() {
    console.log("weight", this.$route.query.weight)
    console.log("country", this.$route.query.country)
    console.log("color", this.$route.query.color)
  }
}
```

Your script could also [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for changes to the params:

```
watch: {
  ["$route.query.weight"](weight, oldWeight) {
    console.log("new weight", weight);
  }
}
```

And you could imperatively push a new route with [`$router.push`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort):

```
methods: {
  searchCanada() {
    this.$router.push({ name: "search", query: { country: "canada" } });
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/8nq9klpz98?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FSearch.vue)

Comment: Thanks for the response and demo @tony19. I forgot to mention that the Vue app is sitting on top of Wordpress which is limiting a bit with what I can do with a router. The current setup is that I have an app that just runs on that search page (and a separate app for the product page)